# Keep getting gcov error when trying to run lcov in Windows command line

Tags: windows, linux, perl, unit-testing, lcov

I was wondering what else is actually needed in order to run lcov in windows command line?  Every time when I run perl lcov, I always get a reminder or errors similar to the following:

```
geninfo: ERROR: need tool gcov!
```

I looked into my bin directory, and couldn't find a gcov.exe.

I normally do perl genhtml filename to get a html test coverage report of my javascript.  I was trying to see if I can do perl lcov as I might want to combine several lcov files into one (and get the total test coverage).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sure does look like you need [gcov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html), doesn't it!

(For cygwin, it looks to be part of the [gcc4-core](http://cygwin.com/packages/gcc4-core) package.)

Comment: @Ether: I'm running cygwin in windows, but I cannot find the gcov.exe in the cygwin directory.  Do you know which package is gcov under in cygwin so I can download it? Thanks.

Comment: @Ether: thanks for the link. I have downloaded and installed the gcov-4.exe. Now I got a new error when doing perl lcov -c: ERROR: need insmod tool (/sbin/insmod) to access kernel coverage data!  I'm trying to run perl lcov under windows. Why does it require so many things and sounded like I need to run it in linux?

Comment: @BeraCim: I'm afraid you're at the limit of my knowledge of cygwin; I haven't used it in a while. It sounds like you have enough material for another SO question though :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I might start another question next week.